# How to redirect after successful import via DataFlow import in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, product, dataflow, import-products

I am using System->Import/Export->Dataflow-Advanced Profiles for importing products to store.

I have inherited ***Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController*** class. Using this it allows me to import profile in popup window.
I have found that is uses ajax for that.
At the end it uses

> Finished profile execution.

To represent the import is done.

Now , how can i redirect from successful import of products to somewhere in my store?

Thanks